# Mysql query WHERE clause targeting a particular distinct taxonomy in table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm trying to get posts with a particular taxonomy. In this case, suppose I were to search a post with the taxonomy 'television' with the value 'SON', I can't figure out which table to query, because there doesn't seem to be a definite id for television. Each instance of television is assigned with a new term_id and term_taxonomy_id.

I am a bit confused on which table I need to Join and on which values.

Please can someone give me some advice, as I think I've already pulled the remained of hair from my balding head. Thanks. my query and DB value are below and The DB diagram follows,

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID,
       MIN(wp_offers.price)
FROM       wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT  JOIN wp_offers             ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_offers.post_id)
WHERE DATE(wp_offers.offer_date) = '2012-05-18'
  AND () # **********the query goes here**********
  AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (8,9)
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'offer'
  AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

---

```
**wp_term_relationships**

object_id        term_taxonomy_id         term_order
10           3                0
10           4                0
10           5                0
21           3                0


**wp_term_taxonomy**

term_taxonomy_id      term_id     taxonomy      description     parent  count
3                 3           television                    0       2
4                 4           television                    0       1
5                 5           television                    0       1


**wp_terms**

term_id         name       slug      term_group
3               SON        SON       0
4               SAM        SAM       0
5               TOS        TOS       0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display them on a page you can just use

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'television' => 'SON' ) );
```

[Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Querying_by_taxonomy)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'television' => 'SON' ) );
```

OR

```
$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'television',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'SON'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

[**Reference.**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)